# unable to use date validation in jsonschema

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, jsonschema

I am unable to use "date" for type validation in jsonschema

```
myschema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "self": {
        "primary_key": ["email"]
    },
    "properties": {
        "email": {
            "pattern": "[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+"
        },
        "dob": {
            "description": "Date of Birth YYYY-MM-DD",
            "type": "date"
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the code below using above schema

```
from jsonschema import validate
validate({ "dob": "2001-02-30"}, myschema)
```

following error trace is obtained

```
Unhandled Exception: 'date' is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'anyOf' in schema['properties']['properties']['additionalProperties']['properties']['type']:
    {'anyOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/simpleTypes'},
               {'items': {'$ref': '#/definitions/simpleTypes'},
                'minItems': 1,
                'type': 'array',
                'uniqueItems': True}]}

On instance['properties']['dob']['type']:
    'date'
```

Update: It seems date is a format and not type but still it is letting me key in an invalid date. I can clearly see in jsonschema code that it tries to parse it using datetime but I am unable to hit breakpoint in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date` should be used as a [*"format"*](http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/#validating-formats), not "type":

```
"dob": {
    "description": "Date of Birth YYYY-MM-DD",
    "type": "string", 
    "format": "date"
}
```

Then, to check the format, use:

```
from jsonschema import validate, FormatChecker

validate({"dob": "2001-02-30"}, myschema, format_checker=FormatChecker())
```